# instead of triggering a download, I am getting gibberish text in response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, .net, webapi

I want to download the zip file without loading it into the browser. However, when I hit the endpoint, instead of triggering a download, I am getting gibberish text in response.

This is my API endpoint.

```
[HttpGet("downloadfile")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Downloadfile(string userId, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        string docId = $"tinyurl:{userId}";
        DocumentResponse response1 = await blobManager.GetCustomUrlByUserId(docId, ct);
        TinyUrl tinyUrl = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TinyUrl>(response1.Content);

      
        var response = await wc.GetAsync(tinyUrl.ActualUrl, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, ct);

        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        var contentStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        var fileName = "file.zip";
        return new FileStreamResult(contentStream, "application/octet-stream")
        {
            FileDownloadName = fileName
        };
    }
```

This is my react code

```
    export const DownloadZip = async (uri) => {
      const method = 'GET';
      const headers = await auth.getTokenHeader(true);
      headers.append('Accept', 'application/octet-stream');
      return retryFetch(uri, { method, headers });
};
```